# Throwing an exception to Main from a Class

Tags: python

I am trying to write a stand alone Class that can be imported. As part of this I'd like to throw exceptions in my Class that can be caught and dealt with in the Main.  Is it possible to throw specific exceptions to Main for the user/developer to deal with?

I'm reasonable comfortable using the try: and except: in the Class and the Main to throw their own exceptions, it's getting the Class to pass a specific exception onto the Main that I can't work out.

Also, is it possible to some how set up the Python class so that it informs the user what exceptions they have to be able to catch to use my specific Class?

Thanks.

Comment: Exceptions are never thrown with a particular recipient.  They are just thrown (and caught by the first one up the call stack with a suitable `except` clause).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the python tutorial section on [user defined exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions) and also the section ["Exceptions are Classes Too"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#exceptions-are-classes-too). You can define your own exceptions as subclasses of the `Exception` class, and then catch them in your main.

Here's a quick example, although the one in the tutorial is better:

```
class MyModuleException(Exception):
    """An exception raised by my module"""

    def __init__(self, message):
        super(MyModuleException, self).__init__(message)
```

and then later in your main method:

```
try:
    myModule.doSomethingExceptional()
except MyModuleException as e:
    print "Oh no!"
```

Lastly, you typically inform the client of your module what exceptions might be raised in the documentation. The [conventions for Python docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) says:

> The docstring for a function or method should summarize its behavior and document its arguments, return value(s), side effects, exceptions raised ...

**Edit:** You should also take a look at [the python library reference on exceptions](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html) for the list of standard exception classes, which may be appropriate for you to subclass.

Comment: to continue on from what I asked Matt, what's the reason for building an additional subclass for standard exceptions? If a standard exception occurs in my class e.g. zerodivisionerror, will the class just drop out due to error and allow it to be picked up in main using a try and except around the class call? Sorry very new to this and still trying to get my head around it.

Comment: You're correct about `ZeroDivisionError`. You typically make the `Exception` subclasses to handle situations that aren't covered by the standard Python exceptions. For instance, a database adapter might throw exceptions like `IntegrityError` if you try to insert the same value twice. That's a special kind of exception that doesn't really map to anything in the Python standard library, so it makes sense to define and use it in that database module.

Comment: @KirkStrauser Thanks Kirk. So I can just let my class fail as long as the user/dev knows to enclose my class call with a try and except to handle any exceptions? Seems to good to be true :). Is there a way print the exception that was called as part of except:? e.g. print "The exception called was %s" % exception.

Comment: Found "print sys.exc_info()" prints the exception being raised.

Comment: @KirkStrauser In the case where I'm writing a stand alone class and I wish to create a unique expection class to go with it, is it possible to intergrate my exception class into my stand alone class? Or does the exception class have to remain seperate and be called by the stand alone class. It seems wrong that I would have to seperately import my exception class just to run my stand alone class. I would assume it's possible to combine the 2 into a single class?

Comment: @user788462 Easier: `try: 1/0` then `except Exception as e: print e`. You'll want your Exception class to be standalone and used like `import mymodule; try: mymodule.dosomething(); except mymodule.FixableError: dosomethingelse()`. Note that you can have a whole hierarchy of exceptions in your module so that `except mymodule.MyModuleException:` can catch any error you raise.

Comment: @KirkStrauser - Thanks again, it's all starting to click :)

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to write a stand alone Class that can be imported. As part of this I'd like to throw exceptions in my Class that can be caught and dealt with in the Main. Is it possible to throw specific exceptions to Main for the user/developer to deal with?

Yes. Presumably if your class exists in another module, you'll need to make sure that main can also import the names of the exceptions that will be thrown.

> I'm reasonable comfortable using the try: and except: in the Class and the Main to throw their own exceptions, it's getting the Class to pass a specific exception onto the Main that I can't work out.

```
class ClassSpecificError(Exception): pass
```

Somewhere in the code for the class:

```
raise ClassSpecificError('the thingy majigged')
```

> Also, is it possible to some how set up the Python class so that it informs the user what exceptions they have to be able to catch to use my specific Class?

No you cannot have checked exceptions in Python.

Comment: Thanks Matt. So just to confirm my understanding, if I just want to use one of the default python exceptions e.g. zerodivisionerror to cover a potential divde by zero exception, I would just note the potentially exception in the class doco and do nothing else (no try or except). Leaving the try and except for the developer to put in their main as part of the class call?

Comment: side note: i try "@Matt", "@matt" and "@mattjoiner" and none seem to stick?

Comment: @user788462: Yes. Document the exceptions that may be thrown or better yet, deal with them inside the class, if it makes sense to do so there. The less exceptions floating around, the better.

Comment: @user788462: Yeah, they made this lame change that all comments notify the poster on which your commenting. Part of that is removing the autocomplete for the poster's name. Dudes are on crack.